# sql server, replace chars in string with values in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlclr

how can i replace values in string with values that are in a table?

for example

```
    select *
into #t
from 
(
    select 'bla'c1,'' c2 union all
    select 'table'c1,'TABLE' c2 union all
    select 'value'c1,'000' c2 union all
    select '...'c1,'' c2
)t1

declare @s nvarchaR(max)='this my string and i want to replace all values that are in table #t'
```

i have some values in my table and i want to replace C1 with C2 in my string.

the results should be

> this my string and i want to replace all 000 that are in TABLE #t

**UPDATE:**
i solved with a CLR

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Data.Linq;

namespace ReplaceValues
{
    public partial class Functions
    {
        [SqlFunction
            (
                //DataAccess = DataAccessKind.Read,
                SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.Read
            )
        ]
        public static string ReplaceValues(string row, string delimitator, string values, string replace/*, bool CaseSensitive*/)
        {
            //return row;
            string[] tmp_values = values.Split(new string[] { delimitator }, StringSplitOptions.None);
            string[] tmp_replace = replace.Split(new string[] { delimitator }, StringSplitOptions.None);

            row = row.ToUpper();

            for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(tmp_values.Length, tmp_replace.Length); i++)
            {
                row = row.Replace(tmp_values[i].ToUpper(), tmp_replace[i]);
            }

            return row;
        }

    }
}
```

and then

```
select *
into #t
from 
(
    select 'value1'OldValue,'one'NewValue union all
    select 'value2'OldValue,'two'NewValue union all
    select 'value3'OldValue,'three'NewValue union all
    select 'value4'OldValue,'four'NewValue
)t1


select dbo.ReplaceValues(t1.column,'|',t2.v,t2.r)
from MyTable t1
cross apply
(
    select dbo.inlineaggr(i1.OldValue,'|',1,1)v,
           dbo.inlineaggr(i1.NewValue,'|',1,1)r
    from #t i1
)t2
```

i have to improved it to manage better the case sensitive, but performance are not bad.
(also 'inlineaggr' is a CLR i wrote years ago)

Comment: Replace them with what? Expected results and a **clear** explanation will help us help you.  Your attempt(s) will also greatly help us understand the problem. A question in your question would also be nice, rather than an unclear problem statement.

Comment: i'm sorry for my explanation (i'm not very good in english). so, i have some values in my table and i want to replace C1 with C2 in my string

Comment: Why does `'values'` get replaced to `'0000'`? In your table `'value'` is replaced with `000`, which would suggest that `'values'` should be `'000s'`.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this via recursion. Assuming you have a table of find-replace pairs, you can number the rows and then use recursive cte:

```
create table #t(c1 nvarchar(100), c2 nvarchar(100));
insert into #t(c1, c2) values
('bla', ''),
('table', 'table'),
('value', '000'),
('...', '');

declare @s nvarchar(max) = 'this my string and i want to replace all values that are in table #t';

with ncte as (
    select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rn, *
    from #t
), rcte as (
    select rn, replace(@s, c1, c2) as newstr
    from ncte
    where rn = 1

    union all

    select ncte.rn, replace(rcte.newstr, ncte.c1, ncte.c2)
    from ncte
    join rcte on ncte.rn = rcte.rn + 1
)
select *
from rcte
where rn = 4
```

Comment: yes, i done the same, but is there not a trick to do it with an inline query?

Comment: There is no other set based solution I could think of. If there are exactly 4 find-replace pairs then you can use nested replace.

Comment: this is only a simple example, but if i have a table with some rows instead of a single string?

Comment: `REPLACE` can only accept a scalar value, and can only replace it with another scalar value, @elle0087 . If you wanted, however, you could convert the above to an **inline** table value function.

Comment: @elle0087 same approach will work with multiple strings. instead of top 1 and order by you need greatest n per group approach.